# .select() from Mongoose doc and count subdocs

Tags: mongoose

The Mongoose collection `Question` has a subdoc field labelled `answers: []`. I want to **run a query that returns relevant `Question` fields *and* the count of the answers.**

My current query is:

```
Question.find()
  .sort({ createdAt: 'desc' })
  .limit(30)
  .select({
    title: 1,
    owner: 1,
    createdAt: 1,
  })
  .populate('owner', 'username')
  .lean()
  .exec((err, questions) => { ... });
```

I want to do something like this:

```
Question.find()
  .sort({ createdAt: 'desc' })
  .limit(30)
  .select({
    title: 1,
    owner: 1,
    createdAt: 1,
    answerCount: answers.length, // give me number of subdocs
  })
  .populate('owner', 'username')
  .lean()
  .exec((err, questions) => { ... });
```

Is there a way to get the count of the subdocs *without returning the full subdoc array (they are large)* and *without running a second query*?

Not a duplicate of [this question asking how to count the number of items in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387969/mongodb-count-the-number-of-items-in-an-array) as I don't want to return the subdocs entirely.

Comment: Why don't you populate `_id` field of answers and count them? `.populate('answers', '_id')`

Comment: Found an answer after following @MedetTleukabiluly and [this answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25965933). I would answer but...